# Issue pulling image when using Skaffold

Tags: kubernetes, skaffold

I'm trying to use Skaffold to deploy some services onto my local minikube cluster, however I am running into issues when it comes to pulling the images. I've specified the Dockerfile and would assume that it would check my local registry and upon not finding the image, proceed to build it and then pull that built image upon pod init.

But it appears as if skaffold is building the image successfully, but when the pod starts up it fails and gives an `Failed to pull image "my-app-image": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: pull access denied for my-app-image, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied`.

I'm a little confused because I thought this would all happening within my local registry, so I'm not sure why it is getting access denined when the image is being built successfully?

Example:

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v2
kind: Config
build:
  artifacts:
    - image: my-app-image
      context: './'
      sync:
        manual:
          - src: 'my-app/**/*'
            dest: '/my-app/'
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-app
spec:
  replicas: 2
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        deploy: example
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: my-app
          image: my-app-image
```

Comment: What repository are you using? Perhaps you use [an insecure one](https://skaffold.dev/docs/environment/image-registries/#insecure-image-registries)?

Comment: Could you please describe how you've set up your local registry, and include command-line you're running and the Skaffold output that you see?